# What's the best alternative to check if an array contains values according to the depreciated NULL constant in php 7.2

Tags: php, arrays, null

I used to check if an array has values like below:

```
$array = array('John', 'Peter', 'Bill', 'Andrew');
if($array != NULL) {
    echo 'Array contains values';
}
else {
    echo 'Array is empty';
}
```

According to php 7.2 about NULL, it says: **This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.**

So what's the best alternative in this situation to check if an array has some values?

```
if( !empty($array) ) {
```

or

```
if( $array != '' ) {
```

or ???

Comment: `empty($array)` is __enough__

Comment: `!empty($array)` is the best way to do it.